# maven compilation error cannot find symbol

Tags: maven

```
 BUILD FAILURE
----------------------
Compilation failure
work\AccountService\src\com\service\accountinquiry\utils\XMLUtil.java:[103,48] cannot find symbol
ymbol  : method parseFloat(java.lang.String,float)
ocation: class com.service.accountinquiry.utils.DataOperationUtils.
```

having weird problem with maven I checked DataOperationUtils.java is already compiled in target folder same folder where XMLutil.java is so why maven is not be able to find DataOperationutils.class in XMLUtils.java
code snippet for XMLUtils.java

```
public static float getNodeTextAsFloat(Node node, String xpath,
            float defaultValue) {
        float returnValue = defaultValue;
        if (node != null) {
            Node tempNode = node.selectSingleNode(xpath);
            if (tempNode != null) {
                String nodeValue = tempNode.getText().trim();
                returnValue = DataOperationUtils.parseFloat(nodeValue,
                        defaultValue);
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
```

I appreciate for your answer thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a compile problem. You sure that the class **DataOperationUtils** has a method called parseFloat that accepts the following types?

1. String
2. float

Possibly you need to typecast the parameters to match?